# jQuery help when unchecking parent I need to toggle the children checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am working on a simple checkbox tree

http://jsfiddle.net/9dvR5/1/

If you click Pacific > California > Bay Area > then an checkbox. If you then uncheck Bay Area the children checkboxes uncheck. So far so good. The problem I am having is if you do this again but this time uncheck California then check it again Bat Area and the children are all unchecked, but if you check Bay Area the toggling is reversed.

How can un-toggle or prevent this from happening.

```
$('.region-group-checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.region-state').toggle();
    $(this).siblings().next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false); 
});
$('.region-state-checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.region-state-area').toggle();
    $(this).siblings().next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false); 
});   
$('.region-state-area-checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.region-state-area-sub').toggle();
    $(this).siblings().next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the property `checked` to `false`, you could trigger a `click` event for these checkboxes.

```
$('.region-group-checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.region-state').toggle();
    $(this)
        .siblings()
        .next()
        .find(':checkbox:checked')
        .trigger('click');
});
$('.region-state-checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.region-state-area').toggle();
    $(this)
        .siblings()
        .next()
        .find(':checkbox:checked')
        .trigger('click');
});
$('.region-state-area-checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.region-state-area-sub').toggle();
    $(this)
        .siblings()
        .next()
        .find(':checkbox:checked')
        .trigger('click'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9dvR5/2/

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but should be easy for you to understand.